# dataTable - can't select all check boxes and make them checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datatable

So I cannot get all of the checked boxes without an error. I am using dataTable but it seems to be erroring out.

Here is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myTable').DataTable({
            "dom": '<"top"fl>rt<"bottom"pi><"clear">'
                /*'<"top"lf>rt<"bottom"p><"clear">'*/
        });
});

    function selectAllUsers() {
        $(':checkbox').each(function () {
            this.checked = true;
        });
        var table = $('#myTable').dataTable({
        });
        var allPages = table.fnGetNodes();
        $('input[type="checkbox"]', allPages).prop('checked', true);
    }
    </script>
```

The code above will select all boxes but then I get a second error message with the dataTable.

but if I do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myTable').DataTable({
            "dom": '<"top"fl>rt<"bottom"pi><"clear">'
                /*'<"top"lf>rt<"bottom"p><"clear">'*/
        });
});

    function selectAllUsers() {
        $(':checkbox').each(function () {
            this.checked = true;
        });
        var table = $('#myTable').dataTable({
        });

    }
    </script>
```

Then I only get the first page checked. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Found solution: https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnGetHiddenNodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnGetHiddenNodes

That will show you how to get non-rendered checkboxes.